# How to dehighlight the row when checkbox is checked in extjs grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am using extjs4.1 grid in aspnet mvc3 application.
I have used checkboxrowselection model.
the issue is :
once the checkbox is checked,the row should not get highlighted in the extjs grid.
How can i acheive this.

please help

Comment: I won't recommend changing the behavior of the checkbox. The checkbox action is to select the row. Is there any reason you want to do that? Maybe there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the checkbox selection model is to select rows.  In extjs, selecting a row means to specifically highlight it, what you want is just a logical selection.  You should be using the user extension: Ext.ux.CheckColumn that ships with the core library. 
To gather the rows, you would need to do a query on the store where the models property is set to true for the data index you define on the checkcolumn.